# Can I, Should I, use promises for loading an Iframe?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

We have a zippy little mobile application with a two panel layout. A container page provides the skeleton, and the panels are implemented as Iframes. We like Iframes because they create a scope, partitioning the panels, but our current method for communicating between panels is nasty. Panel 1 assigns its calling parameters in global scope, then calls Panel2.location() to load the page. The onload handler of Panel2 looks for the previously assigned calling parameters, and does it's business. If there's an HTTP error, the caller never knows, and the error goes straight to the screen.

With promises, I should be able to do something much nicer. Loading Panel2 is an asynch operation. I would love to be able to do this...

```
Panel2.myAsynchLoad("myNewPage.html").then(
    function(myNewPage){
        myNewPage.someFunc( calling, parameters, passed, directly );
    },
    function(err){
        ...errors notified to caller
    }
);
```

But writing myAsynchLoad(), I run straight into problems. If I load panel2 with location(), I have, it seems, no way of retrieving HTTP errors. If I use XmlHttpRequest and document.write(), it's not a normal page load, and scripts in the new page are not registered.

Is there a nice way to do this ? Should I even be here in the first place ? Answers not using jquery appreciated.

Comment: if nothing else, using the first method you should be able to get errors using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror - though, there's no indication on that page as to how universal this is

Comment: I don't think promises solve anything you couldn't do with callbacks here. I.e. promises seem orthogonal to your problem. Can you, and should you use promises for everything? Yes! ([almost](http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/promises-guide#when-not-to-use)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone makes it back here, I implemented my function. My solution is to call the url twice. Once with xmlHttpRequest to trap any errors, then window.location() with the same url. If the caching headers are set correctly the page is served from browser cache without a second call to the server. And it lets me treat pages as objects, on which I can call functions, with error handling right through, so yes I think it's pretty cool.

```
var waitingCaller = [];
function goP(panel, url) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        //first retrieve via AJAX to put in browser cache and recover eventual errors
        getUrl(url).then(
            function (xhr) {
                //ignore the response and change location with same url
                waitingCaller[panel] = resolve; //We're not storing reject because we can't trap errors. From here we assume success.
                panels[panel].contentWindow.location = url;
            },
            function (err) { reject(err) }
        )
    });
}
function connectWaitingCaller(panel,event) {
    waitingCaller[panel](panels[panel].contentWindow); //Call resolve, passing window reference
    waitingCaller[panel] = null; //caller no longer waiting
}
panels[1].addEventListener("load", connectWaitingCaller.bind(this, 1));
```

To use it...

```
goP(1, "SomeNewPage.php")
.then( function(SomeNewPage){
    SomeNewPage.myFunc();
});
```

My getUrl utility function, to make the answer complete...

```
//requêtes HTTP avec Promises !
//returns xhr object, used by getUrlAsXXX() functions
function getUrl(url) {
    // Return a new promise.
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        // Do the usual XHR stuff
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url);

        xhr.onload = function () {
            // This is called even on 404 etc
            // so check the status
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                // Resolve the promise with the request object
                // so downstream functions have full access.
                resolve(xhr);
            }
            else {
                // Otherwise reject with the status text
                // which will hopefully be a meaningful error
                reject(Error(xhr.status + " \"" + xhr.statusText + "\" while getting " + url));
            }
        };

        // Handle network errors
        xhr.onerror = function () {
            reject(Error("Network Error"));
        };

        // Make the request
        xhr.send();
    });
}
```